# How can I include compiled binaries in a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I'm developing an open source project and am trying to figure out how to incorporate the [JPen](https://sourceforge.net/p/jpen/code/HEAD/tree/) library into it.  This is an open source library available on sourceforge that wraps drivers so you can use digital tablets in Java.

Unfortunately the project no longer seems to be maintained and the pom included in the source does not work.  I've spent some time tweaking the pom file, but am unable to get it to build.  Fortunately, the compiled binaries do work and I can use them in non-maven projects that I build and run with Ant.

I'd like to get this working with maven cut can't find any info on how to do so.  Since this project is not published on central and since I can't build the project on my own machine, I'm left trying to figure out how to get Maven to recognize the compiled binaries as a dependency.  These libraries include some compiled binaries using JNI, so that may throw in a twist beyond just including a jar file.

Anyone know how I would add this dependency to my maven project?

Comment: If you have the jar file, you can just follow the instructions [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) adding the dependency to your project pom. Anyway I suggest you to try to figured out how to build the source code or find a maintained library.

Comment: That's useful for my own repository, but if I want to publish this on git hub, how would I include it?  I don't want to make every user manually install this library on their system just to build my code.

Comment: As the explanation was too long I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the fast way to solve using *Maven* it to install the jar as a dependency manually, as explained in the *Maven* documentation linked in my [comment](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

You can use the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Providing a proper *group-id*, *artifact-id*, *version* and *packagin* you have all the info to import the dependency in your pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId><group-id></groupId>
        <artifactId><artifact-id></artifactId>
        <version><version></version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

That will solve the build problem on your machine.

If you share your project, than you have to perform a step further.

If you share in your company, than is a good practice to have an internal repository like *artifactory* or *nexus*.

In such case you just need to upload your new local dependency manually to your company repository and then all your coulleuges should be able to build your project without any manual action.

If you want to publish your project as an open source project and make it available for every one, than you have a different path to follow.

You can just add the dependency on your pom, then write on the *README* how to install manually the jar and where to obtain it.

The last possibility I see, is that you take ownership of the project making a fork.

That should be always possible with open source license, but take care and have a look of it.

Once you fork the code, you have to build it your own, I read you can't do it, but you should fix the problems and make a build.

At that point you're able to publish on Maven central repository.

A good starting point is to contact the original author and ask for permission and help to do that.